# Apache redirect rule for special character in request_URI

Tags: apache

I want to redirect a URL having `REQUEST_URI` like `/wordpress-mu/success-academy-student/how-to-use-smartbook-2/#.X5CejUJKhTY` to some destination URL. If I use redirect permanent, `#.X5CejUJKhTY` is getting appended to the destination URL. If I use `rewritecond` it is going to last default rule.